# ¿Como almacenar una foto de perfil, descripcion, y demas cosas de un usuario en firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-auth, firestore

Bien, me solicitaron hacer una aplicacion en donde lso trabajadores (usuarios) tengan su propio "perfil", en el cual tengan diversos datos como su fotografia, alguna descripcion, su edad y demas campos. Entiendo que en una tipica base de datos SQL (Ej. MySQL) por poner un ejemplo muy burdo, se pone todo en la tabla usuario y pues de ahi deriva todo lo demas.

El detalle es que me solicitan hacerlo en Firebase, y de ser honesto con ustedes, nuca lo he usado. Ya comence a leer la documentacion y demas; usamos Firebase Auth para el tema de la sesion y credenciales del mismo, usamos en concreto correo y contraseña. El detalle es que Firebase Auth guarda solo eso, correo y contraseña, por lo que mi duda es: ¿Como o en donde puedo guardar la foto de perfil, descripcion, edad y demas en Firestore?

¿Como hago ese "Puente" para tener la informacion de los usuarios con su registro de autentificacion?

Esto lo estoy haciendo en flutter 2.8.1.

Agradezco sus respuestas. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hay bastante info sobre Flutter con Firebase Auth, Firestore y para el almacenamiento de datos puedes usar Firebase Storage

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Puedes vincular tu auth de firebase con firestore para almacenar en este último datos de estos mismo usuarios, revisa la documentación sobre firestore para ello.